# Customize matplotlib axis to show all values within certain range

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, axis-labels

I have the following csv data:

```
x,y
1,5
2,3
4,4
5,7
8,3
9,4
```

Which I can easily plot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Ojs.png

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("graph.csv")

print(df.dtypes)

df.plot.bar(x='x', y='y')
```

As you can see, in my original data I have no values for x=3, x= 6, x= 7 and x=10. Let's suppose the complete data should go until 10.

Is it possible to, without modifying the csv, define the range (0,10) and add to the plot the x values which are not in the csv with a y value equal to 0 ? Like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqqwX.png

I couldn't find any documentation on how to achieve this ! Many thanks

Comment: What you ask for is the default in case you do not plot strings. So convert your strings to numbers and you will get the desired plot; or else read [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I thought but I checked the types of my data and both columns are int64.

Comment: Did you read and understand [mcve]?

Comment: Yes, I have. Will take it into account for the future. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

If it can be helpful for anyone, I am posting how I have solved it. The data, where x are hours, is the following:

```
x,y
0:30,5
1:00,3
2:30,4
6:00,7
9:00,3
13:00,4
15:30,8
17:30,5
20:00,7
22:30,2
23:30,6
```

And the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_csv("graph.csv")

df['x'] = pd.to_datetime(df['x'])

df = df.set_index(["x"])

s = dt.datetime.strptime('00:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
r = []
r.append(s.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

for i in range(30,60*24,30):
    r.append((s+dt.timedelta(minutes=i)).strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

row = [0]

r = pd.to_datetime(r)

for i in r:
    if i in df.index:
        pass
    else:
        df.loc[i] = row

df.sort_index(inplace=True)

df.sum(level=0).plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(50,30),edgecolor='k', linewidth=1, width=1)
```